# Laravel SOAP Server & Client: Method not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, soap, laravel-5.5

I try to setup a SOAP Server for Laravel Framework 5.5.13. Therefore I have created two classes (Server.php and Client.php) and two Controllers, SoapServerController and SoapClientController.

Here's the source code:

app/Classes/Soap/Server.php

```
namespace App\Classes\Soap;

class Server {
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function getDate() {
        return date('Y-m-d');
    }

}
```

app/Classes/Soap/Client.php

```
namespace App\Classes\Soap;

class Client {

    protected $instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $params = array( 'uri' => '/soap/server',
                         'location' => url('/soap/server'),
                         'trace' => 1,
                         'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
                         );

        $this->instance = new \SoapClient( null, $params );

    }

    public function getDate() {
        return $this->instance->getDate();
    }

}
```

app/Http/Controllers/SoapServerController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Classes\Soap;

class SoapServerController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $params = array( 'uri' => url('/soap/server') );
        $server = new \SoapServer( null, $params );
        $server->setClass( Soap\Server::class );
        $server->handle();
    }

}
```

app/Http/Controllers/SoapClientController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Classes\Soap;

class SoapClientController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $client = new Soap\Client;
        $client->getDate();
    }
}
```

When I open the route /api/soap/client, I get the error:

> SoapFault: Method Not Allowed

Do I have to change something in my routes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that SOAP calls are all supposed to be performed with POST requests. Most likely, you have your route set up with only GET requests, hence the method (POST) is not allowed.